# Coproducts exist in the category of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

This is a part of the proof that coproducts exist in the category of groups. I took it from the book *Algebra* by Serge Lang.

> *Proof*: Let $\{G(i) \mid i \in I\}$ be a family of groups. We let $C$ be the category whose objects are families of group homomorphisms $\{g(i)\colon G(i) \to G \mid i \in I\}$ and whose morphisms are the obvious ones. ...

What are the obvious morphisms? The proof that is given in the book is not clear for me, I would also like to see a proof of the fact that coproducts exist in the category of groups.

Comment: Given two such families $\{g(i):G(i)\to G\}$ and $\{g'(i):G(i)\to G'\}$, a morphism from the first to the second is a homomorphism $\phi:G\to G'$ such that $g'(i) = \phi\circ g(i)$ for each $i$.

Comment: Is that the way its usually defined ?

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(category_theory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be groups, then $C$ (with homomorphisms $i_a : A \to C$, $i_b : B \to C$) is the coproduct if given any $C'$ with group homomorphisms $a:A \to C'$,  $b:B \to C'$ there exists a unique map $i : C \to C'$ such that $a = i \circ i_a$ and $b = i \circ i_b$. That's just taking the general definition of a coproduct and writing it out with "groups" instead of "objects" and "group homomorphisms" instead of "morphisms" so we haven't done anything yet.

Now I claim that if we let $C$ be the free product of groups $A \star B$ (which always exists) and $i_a,i_b$ the inclusion maps then this is the coproduct. Recall that the free product of groups is the set of words made from the alphabet $A \cup B$, reducing when possible. (**example:** in $\{T,F\}\star \mathbb R^\times$ the elements $T\cdot \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2\cdot F\cdot 3\cdot T$ and $T\cdot  2\cdot T\cdot \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot 6\cdot F\cdot F$ are equal but $T3F$ is not equal to $3TF$).

To prove this assume some $C'$ with maps $a,b$ as before, we need to provide a unique $i : C \to C'$ that satisfies the equations. Given that all we really have to go with is the definition of free product and the use of the maps $a,b$, if you think about how to do this for a while you might come up with the following idea.

Map $T\cdot \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2\cdot F\cdot 3\cdot T \in C$ to $a(T)\cdot b(\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2)\cdot a(F)\cdot b(3)\cdot a(T) \in \mathbb C'$. Defining this map formally would be a bit of a nightmare notationally so we'll just call it $i$ and it does satisfy the properties $a = i \circ i_a$,  $b = i \circ i_b$ because if you take a word $w$ from $A$ (resp. $B$) and apply it to the RHS of the equation you get $a(w)$ (resp. $b(w)$) which is the same as the LHS.

To show uniqueness suppose there was some map $i'$ with the same properties. Since $i'$ is a group homomorphism given words $w_a \in A$ and $w_b \in B$ $$i'(i_a(w_a) \cdot i_b(w_b)) = a(w_a) \cdot b(w_b)$$ it should be obvious how to prove $i' = i$ by induction on the number of times an element of $C$ changes from words in $A$ to words in $B$ but actually writing it out wouldn't give any further insight.

Comment: Why $T\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot F\cdot3\cdot T=T\cdot2\cdot T\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot6\cdot F\cdot F$? Or $T\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot F\cdot3\cdot T=T\cdot2\cdot F\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot6\cdot F\cdot F$?

Comment: We know that the coproducts of Abelian groups are the direct sums. Can you tell me why the above proof does not apply to Abelian groups?

Comment: @Kyson Forming the free product of two abelian groups isn't guaranteed to give you another abelian group (so the construction doesn't work in AbGrp).

Answer (score 11):

For the proof that coproducts of groups exist, see also any book on combinatorial group theory,  but I also recommend that this notion is seen in the context of the category of groupoids admirably described in the downloadable book [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html).

The point is that a disjoint union $D= \sqcup_i G_i$ of groups is naturally a groupoid; and for any groupoid $G$ with object set $X$ and function $f: X \to Y$ there is a groupoid $U_f(G)$ with object set $Y$ and satisfying a nice universal property. In particular, if $Y$ is a singleton, we get the *universal group* $U(G)$ of the groupoid. In particular, $U(D)$ is the coproduct of the groups $G_i$.

A fact related to homotopy theory and the fundamental group of the circle is that if $\mathcal I$ is the groupoid with two objects $0,1$ and only two nonidentity morphisms,  $\iota: 0 \to 1$ and $\iota^{-1}: 1 \to 0$ then $U(\mathcal I)$ is the group $\mathbb Z$ of integers!

If you take a disjoint union $D$ of copies of $\mathcal I$, indexed by a set $S$, say, and then take $U(D)$, you get the free group on the set $S$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1)

Comment: We know that the coproducts of Abelian groups are the direct sums. Can you tell me why the proofs for group coproduct being free product does not apply to Abelian groups?

Comment: @velutluna, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234274/coproducts-exist-in-the-category-of-groups#comment2288718_234299), it does! … ish.  The catch is that we have to stay within the category of Abelian groups.  If you take the Abelianisation of the free product $A * B$, where $A$ and $B$ are Abelian groups, then you get $A \oplus B$ (and similarly even for infinite coproducts).