# Prove that the homomorphisms of an coproduct of two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is a follow up to my last: [How to write down the coproduct of two groups explicitly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805280/how-to-write-down-the-coproduct-of-two-groups-explicitly/2805314#2805314)

I should prove that $\iota_1, \iota_2$ are injective if $(C, \iota_1, \iota_2)$ is the coproduct of the groups $G_1, G_2$. And argue why this isn't the case in the class of all rings with unit.

My proof: 
Since $C$ is a the coproduct there is a unique homomorphism $f: C \rightarrow D$ for a homomorphism $\phi_1: G_1 \rightarrow G_1$ with $\phi=f \circ \iota_1$. Let $D:=G_1$ and  $\phi_1=id_{G_1}$.

$\iota_1(g)=\iota_1(h) \Rightarrow f(\iota_1(g))=f(\iota_1(h)) \Rightarrow \phi_1(g)=\phi_1(h) \Rightarrow g=h$

Hence $\iota_1$ is injective. Analogous for $\iota_2.$

First of all, have I missed something? And secondly which step doesn't work for rings with unit? (My guess was that the zero ring could make troubles but that's not more then a guess right now.)

Comment: The universal property of the coproduct only gives you a unique homomorphism $C\to D$ if you have *both* a homomorphism $G_1\to D$ *and* a homomorphism $G_2\to D$. What homomorphism are you using for $G_2\to G_1$?

Comment: I didn't specify $\phi_2$ because I didn't need to for the injectivity of  f. Are you implying that I do need it and just don't see how?

Comment: edit: i meant injectivity of $\iota_1$

Comment: $f$ exists if *and only if* there are two homomorphisms $G_1\to D$ and $G_2\to D$. For your purposes it doesn't matter what homomorphism $\phi_2$ is, but it does have to exist. Of course, for the category of groups there will be no trouble finding a $\phi_2$. (Why?) For the category of rings (with unit), though, this stops your argument immediately. (Why?)

Comment: okay, i think i have it now. in the category of groups i can always find a homomorphism $\phi_2$ because i can always choose the constant one which maps everything to the neutral element $e_{G_1}$.  But in the category of rings with unit I find a counterexample: $G_1=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $G_2=\mathbb{Z}_3$. With these rings D has to be the zero ring (beause the maps $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ have to be homomorphic) and therefore I can't just take the identity map for $\phi_1$.